# Solving for texture projection on planar surface

Tags: opengl, reflection, texture-mapping, render-to-texture, plane

im coding with freebasic and i`m using opengl 1.1 for 3d.

how i can project a texture on a planar surface (water)?

Is there a way in opengl where i can manipulate the texture matrix that my texture is always all over the screen exactly one time. Because my reflection texture is a exact copy of the camera view.

Comment: You have to draw a full-screen quad and use the screen position as texture coordinates (more or less). But the reflection texture should be rendered with a reflected view.

Comment: My reflection texture is rendered reflected.
But how am i getting the right matrix for the texture?
I have no clue and i found no tutorial which explains it to me.

Comment: I tested something and now its working.

Comment: What matrix do you mean? You don't need any matrix for a simple full screen quad and sampling in screen space.

Comment: I understand you, but this fullscreen texture needs to be on the water surface.
I solved the problem with texgen and texture matrix manipulation. Now i have a perfect reflecting water surface.